# Proof of the equation for the perpendicular distance of a point from a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have a question in my textbook asking me to prove the equation $perpendicular\ distance=|\frac{aX+bY+cZ-d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}|$ for the distance from the point $P(X,Y,Z)$ to the plane $ax+by+cz=d$

It has asked me to use a method where a point $T$ is chosen on the plane, and $M$ refers to the foot of the perpendicular, and $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{PM}$ and $\vec{PT}$ . My working so far is that:
$$PM=PTcos\theta$$
Therefore as
$$\vec{PM}\cdot\vec{PT}=|\vec{PM}||\vec{PT}|cos\theta$$
$$PM=\frac{\vec{PM}\cdot\vec{PT}}{|\vec{PM}|}$$
I know that $|\vec{PM}|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ but how do I work out the top part?. I don't know where to start. Am I correct in thinking $\vec{PM} =a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}+c\hat{k}$

Comment: Well, if you have the equation of the plane, you have the normal vector of it using the coeficients of $x,y,z$. Then, $n=(a,b,c)$. To evaluate the distance from a point to a plane you have to start from a generic point (moving point) of the plane, for example $(x',y',z')$ and goes to the direction of the normal vector until reach the disered point. So parametrize this vector and evaluate its norm. In this case you have to choose a moving point of the plane, and find the vector that links both points in the plane, then, the distance vector and this one are perpendicular, use scalar product.

Comment: Maybe you can use orthogonal projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ be a point in our plain such that

$(X-x_0,Y-y_0,Z-z_0)||(a,b,c)$, which says that there is $\lambda$ for which
$$(X-x_0,Y-y_0,Z-z_0)=\lambda(a,b,c).$$
Hence, our distance (let be $\rho$) it's
$$\rho=\sqrt{(X-x_0)^2+(Y-y_0)^2+(Z-z_0)^2}=|\lambda|\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$$
In another hand, $x_0=X-\lambda a$, $y_0=Y-\lambda b$ and $z_0=Z-\lambda c$.

Thus,$$a(X-\lambda a)+b(Y-\lambda b)+ c(Z-\lambda c)-d=0,$$
which gives
$$\lambda=\frac{aX+bY+cZ-d}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$ and from here
$$\rho=\left|\frac{aX+bY+cZ-d}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\right|\cdot\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=\frac{|aX+bY+cZ-d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$
and we are done!